# passing variables into onclick method in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Passing variables into onclick method.How do I do it in HTML and javascript

I am passing the variable usersid from the onclick calling funtion to called function.

```
<tbody>
                {% for each_user in detail %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ each_user.userss_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ each_user.userss_email }}</td>     

                    <td><input class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="Edit" id="edit"
                            onclick="editUser('\''+ '{{ each_user.userss_id }}' +'\'')"></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

My script code is

```
        <script>
            function edituser(user_id) {
                console.log(user_id);
                document.location.href = "/'{{ user_id }}'/user/edit/"
            }
        </script>
```

What is the expected result is when I click the edit button it should take me to the url /user_id/user/edit. So user id is the integer here.So I shoule see /1/user/edit.
But what I am getting here is http:/""/interviewer/edit and page not found error also.
So I dont know how to pass the variable to the url.

Comment: This is not javascript.

Comment: Looks like ejs file

Comment: All the script I have saved it in the one html file

Comment: Have you checked what that template (it looks kind of like Jinja template, but it could be something else too) actually translates to? You should see it with browser's inspect element tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <script>
            function edituser(user_id) {
                console.log(user_id);
                document.location.href = "/" + user_id + "/user/edit/"
            }
        </script>
```

user_id doesn't need to be in {{}}

Comment: For example if a user_id is 1,I am getting /'1'/user/edit.is there anyway to remove the quotes '1' in userid?

Comment: Make onclick as onclick="editUser('{{ each_user.userss_id }}')

Comment: I am getting an error if I change the onlcick to this editUser('{{ each_user.userss_id }}') ,the error is site cannot be reached

Answer (score 1):

edit your `document.location.href` like below should works. The issue is  `user_id` is a javascript variable, not a template variable, so you don't wrap it with {{ }}.

```
 <script>
            function edituser(user_id) {
                console.log(user_id);
                document.location.href = "/" + user_id + "/user/edit/"
            }
</script>
```